# Stacking Order: How to render component so it appears on top of parents' sibling who renders afterwards

Tags: react-native, position, css-position, z-index

I'm having some problems with zIndex and position whilst styling a drop down list (react-native-menu). I want to make the drop down list appear on top of all other components on this scene when it's clicked. I'm trying to use zIndex and position but maybe not doing it correctly?

In my code (below), I'm rendering a hierarchy where `Card` > `CardSection` > various subcomponents of each. The drop down list consists of the components `MenuContext` (config) and `TopNavigation` (main drop down list).

```
return (
<Card>
  <CardSection style={{zIndex: 2}}>
    <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
      <Image style={thumbnailStyle}
        source={{ uri: "" }}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={headerContentStyle}>
      <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Tam</Text>
      <Text>tam@tam</Text>
    </View>
    <MenuContext style={{ flex:1, zIndex:6, position:'absolute', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end' }} >
      <TopNavigation/> //this is 
    </MenuContext>
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection style={{zIndex: 1}}>
    <Text style={{zIndex: 2}}>{props.post.body}</Text>
  </CardSection>
</Card>
)
```

So the drop down is a child of the first `CardSection`. I've got it to appear over it's own parent `CardSection` but I can't get it to appear on top of the second `CardSection` that renders after. So I can't get it to show on top of it's parent's sibling.

I'm reluctant to use some plugin or workaround.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

So what was making it so hard to render the popup menu above things on the z-axis was the sibling of it's parent. So what helped me get the results I needed was looking more macro and moving `<ContextMenu/>` higher in the component hierarchy, out of this component altogether and into it's parent.

I should have inferred this since the docs for the original package I used had `ContextMenu` in the entry point to the app and comments such as:

```
 // You need to place a MenuContext somewhere in your application,usually at the root. 
  // Menus will open within the context, and only one menu can open at a time per context.
```

My mistake was getting lost in the micro world of `zIndex` and `position` and assuming that what looked like a styling problem should be solved with a styling solution. I forgot about the bigger picture.